# What does '(:0)' in the output of the command 'who' mean?

Tags: command-line, xorg, who

When I type `who` in terminal I get this output:

```
$USER      tty2         2017-01-12 12:50 (:1)
```

What does this smiley `(:1)` mean ?

Sometimes this smiley looks like `(:0.0)`. What does it mean in this case?

Where is an overview about these different brackets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can find out in the manpage by typing `man who`, you can enable column headings with the `-H` option:

```
$ who -H
NAME          LINE         TIME             COMMENT
bytecommander tty7         2017-01-12 15:26 (:0)
guest-c62iz5  tty8         2017-01-12 15:40 (:1)
```

I have to agree this is not very helpful though, and the manpage also doesn't contain any explanation of the values.

However, I think I can tell you what these columns mean anyway:

- `NAME` is the username of each logged in user.
- `LINE` seems to contain the TTY through which the user is logged in (TTY1-6 are terminals, TTY7-12 are used by the X display server to show graphical desktops; you switch between them using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1 - F12</kbd>).
- `TIME` is the date and time when the user logged in to their current session.
- `COMMENT` in our cases shows the content of the `$DISPLAY` environment variable (normally `:0`) in braces, which is also used by the X display server. Only graphical TTYs should have such a value, this column is empty for me on the terminal TTYs.

  You can check the value of this variable using the command `echo $DISPLAY`. What exactly it means is described e.g. in [What does DISPLAY=:0.0 actually mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16815/103151) and [What is DISPLAY=:0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193827/103151).

Answer (score 10):

From the `info` page (`info coreutils 'who invocation'`)

> If given no non-option arguments, ‘who’ prints the following
>   information for each user currently logged on: login name, terminal
>   line, login time, **and remote hostname or X display**.

So `(:0)` simply means X display number 0 on the localhost.

If there are remote users (for example SSH sessions) as well, you may see something like

```
$ who
steeldriver tty7         2016-12-15 13:57 (:0)
steeldriver pts/4        2017-01-12 09:32 (192.168.1.4)
```